# Why include opencv header from opencv2 directory?

Tags: opencv3.0

I've installed last version of opencv.
I've followed some C++ tutorials and i do not understand something.

I have to include some files files like that

```
    #include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
```

When i print CV_VERSION constant value, it says me 3.1.0. This is the latest version.

So why should i include files in opencv2 directory and not opencv3 ?

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you don't include it?

Comment: i've some errors (symbols undefined).
In fact i just want to know why there is no opencv3 folder in opencv

Comment: there is no opencv3 folder! you can find details [here](http://docs.opencv.org/master/db/dfa/tutorial_transition_guide.html#gsc.tab=0)

Comment: My question is "why there is no opencv3 folder ? The version is 3"

Answer (score 2):

The `opencv2` you include does not mean release 2.x. That is the folder that contains the header for all releases (2.x 3.x 4.x etc.) You can see that from [opencv Github](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/4.3.0/include). The same folder is found under 2.4, 3.4, and 4.3.

I don't know where the name comes from. But someone explained [here](https://answers.opencv.org/question/4397/include-folder-structure-opencv-andor-opencv2/) that

> "folder opencv contains the header files for old fashion C style opencv functions and the folder opencv2 contains the headers for the new and more flexible C++ interface"